# Old Laptop Falsely Generating KeyDown/KeyPressed Event

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard

My ~10 years old laptop is exhibiting some rather odd behavior.

Somehow Windows thinks that there's an unrecognized key that has been pressed by the user. This is not a big deal at all, however, it gets annoying when I try to right click on items for context menu options, in which case, the context menu shows up and disappears in a matter of single second or less, all because Windows is being sent an ambiguous signal by my laptop's hardware which it seems to interpret as a key pressed event.

Since this made me curious, I wrote down a quick program to check what key Windows recognizing it as and I've posted a screenshot of the same.

Does anyone here know how to suppress this message so that Windows ignores it completely and thus I can interact with context menus without them disappearing on me?

[Windows KeyDown Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFbDR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Installed AutoHotKey and created a script to suspend the KeyDown Event messages.

Code:

```
SC10D::Return
```

There's another solution to this but it would require some Windows programming knowledge.

Basically, write a program that executes Windows function RegisterHotKey(...) and use that to register the constant and erroneous KeyDown events and after catching the event code the program so that it does nothing.